# Chrome on laptop cannot see Shield TV when casting?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

When I try to cast a tab from Chrome on my laptop, I only see my Google Home devices (audio only).  I cannot see my NVidia Shield TV.  I have rebooted the Shield and my laptop.  I can cast to my Shield from my phone without issue.

If I open Youtube on my laptop I can click the Cast button and I do see the Shield (in the same dialog as before) but when I click it it says it's casting but it doesn't actually change anything. It keeps playing in my browser and my TV doesn't change.

Edit: I lied. I cannot cast from my phone. It tries then says "Casting to Shield has ended".  This worked less than a week ago.  Must be something wrong with the shield.

Answer (score 0):

I used the "Uninstall updates" feature on the Shield and now it's working.

Working version is 1.33.133253

I will try to capture the non-working version if it updates again.